# "The Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 provider is not installed on your local machine" Exception is thrown while connecting to Access database

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I've been trying to connect a Microsoft database file to my Visual Basic application.

But when I try to connect it using code, it runs but as soon as I click the button to check the credentials it crashes (visual studio says it crashes in the bold area)

Code:

```
Dim con As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.jet.oledb.4.0;data   source=P:\POS System\POS System Database.mdb")
Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM Login Info WHERE    Username = 'user" & txtStaffID.Text & "' AND password = 'user" &     txtPassword.Text & "' ", con)
con.Open()
Dim sdr As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
If (sdr.Read() = True) Then
'Pass verification and go to main form.
 Me.Hide()
 Else
 MsgBox("Sorry, The Username or Password was incorrect.",   MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Information")
 End If
```

but when I try to connect it through the wizard, i get this error:

> The Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 provider is not installed on your local machine

Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: Please add code here directly.

Comment: It won't let me add it even if I use the backticks, ill give it another go

Comment: Got it working.

Comment: Hint: Improve your `OleDbCommand` by using the `OleDbCommand.Parameters`-Attribute. Right now it's absolutly easy to `inject your database`. Just put a `'` into one of the `TextBoxes` before using this code to see an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

had that issue just yesterday.
install [2007 Office System Driver](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23734) and restart visual studio.

BTW, its a better practice to use `ExecuteScalar()` in order to to find a match between user and password in a login form:

```
  Dim result As Integer = 0
        Dim con As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.jet.oledb.4.0;data   source=P:\POS System\POS System Database.mdb")
        Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Login Info WHERE    Username = 'user" & txtStaffID.Text & "' AND password = 'user" & txtPassword.Text & "' ", con)
        con.Open()
        result = DirectCast(cmd.ExecuteScalar(), Integer)
        con.Close()
        If result > 0 Then
            'Pass verification and go to main form.
            Me.Hide()
        Else
            MsgBox("Sorry, The Username or Password was incorrect.", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Information")
        End If
```

Comment: Thanks! I am now getting this error though when I enter anything

http://imgur.com/a/TUWFM

Comment: you have to change your connection string (you are now using ACE engine not JET). also what is the P:\ drive? its not a physical path - use the root directory. please read that: http://www.connectionstrings.com/access/

Comment: also what version of Access do you use? its better to use .accdb file and not old mdb.

Comment: I see there is a 2010 version of AccessDatabaseEngine.exe
 out there as well.