# error 'The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine' when import excel file

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, excel

I need to import excel to OleDB

When I do an import and I get the error

> The provider '`Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0`' is not registered on the
>   local machine.

We will not put the whole code to be more than 100 lines only in the block and the error hide does not open.

These two tools can not be installed.

Observation: with formarts `.xls` works and with formats `.xlsx` don't works

Is there another possibility?

```
try
    {
        if (Request.Files.Count > 0)
        {
            HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files[0];
            db.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
            db.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;

            string excelPath = Server.MapPath("~/temp/") + Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
            file.SaveAs(excelPath);

            string conString = string.Empty;
            string extension = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
            switch (extension)
            {
                case ".xls": //Excel 97-03
                    conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Excel03ConString"].ConnectionString;
                    break;
                case ".xlsx": //Excel 07 or higher
                    conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Excel07+ConString"].ConnectionString;
                    break;
                case ".XLSX": //Excel 07 or higher
                    conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Excel07+ConString"].ConnectionString;
                    break;

            }


            conString = string.Format(conString, excelPath);
            using (OleDbConnection excel_con = new OleDbConnection(conString))
            {
                excel_con.Open();
            } 
        }
    }


   catch (Exception erro1)
    {
        mensagem = "Erro! " + erro1.Message;
    }

    return RedirectToAction("Importacao_Contratos", "ImportaContratosAux", new { mensagem = mensagem });
}
```

Comment: Install the ACE 12.0 driver. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255

Comment: check my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39292976/5718868 @JacobH for a mysterious reason ACE 12.0 driver is not solving this problem he should install 2007 Office System Driver

Comment: Probably just x86 vs x64 version to be honest. Hope that works though!

Comment: i try x86, don't work's iden

Comment: Sorry, the solution will be in the machine client, i can't installl other applications, like OLEDB e o AcessDatabaseEngine

Comment: Can you assure/assume that the client will have Excel installed? And are you really limited to 100 lines of code?

Comment: Yes, the client will have Excel installed... and cause the error it is in excel_con.open(); the rest don't import in the error

Comment: so @JacobH, 
Any idea?

Comment: Can you use third party libraries? If so, I believe openXML (might have remembered the name wrong) can handle xlsx as well. Worth a google

Comment: yeah, i can, but...

Comment: Interop perhaps?